# Check whether the contacts in my address book (OS X Lion) use Skype

Tags: osx-lion, skype

Does anyone know how to check whether the contacts in my address book (OS X Lion) use Skype?

Comment: Looks like you can just automatically take them over into skype according to a screenshot [here](http://www.dslreports.com/forum/r25932085-Skype-for-Mac-importing-contacts) but I don't have a mac to check

Comment: ok, I understand it now. The problem is that I do not still know who has Skype account

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Broadcast an email and ask them. Other than that, you'd need to search Skype for each one.  With some cleverness it may be possible to automate this but it's probably not worth it for other than intellectual challenge.  And even then, there will be multiples (how do you choose the right one?) and no-hits (f/ex, my Skype-name is a nickname that wouldn't be in my friends' address books).

Edit: It looks like Skype 2.8 does have an option to import from Address Book. I can't say how effective it is.

Comment: do it for each one is a pain. I would try to use some windows version or whatever